# Code Error import mysql.connector as m ModuleNotFoundError:

Tags: python, mysql

this
import mysql.connector as m
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'

error shows up when this code is running

```
import mysql.connector as m
db = m.connect(host = "localhost", user = "root", password = "0000")
cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute("create database if not exists periodic_table")
cur.execute("use periodic_table")
cur.execute("create table if not exists elements(symbol varchar(2) primary key, name varchar(20), atomic_number int, mass float)")
db.commit()
```

pls help

i tried and keep failing

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked whether the 'mysql-connector-python' package is properly installed or not?
Try
pip show mysql-connector-python

If it is not installed, use
pip install mysql-connector-python